# Python tkinter window runs a second time after code is finished running when importing variables to a different module

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have two modules. main.py initializes my tkinter ui, stores some variables, and sends them to compute.py. compute.py then needs to send the variables back to main.py, where they are printed to console. After my code successfully executes, the gui window pops up a second time.

I have tried putting root.destroy() in every place I can think of. It tells me my window is already destroyed, but it still shows the ui for whatever reason.

I've googled around and looked at tkinter tutorials and nothing deals with an issue like this. I have used multiple modules before and have never ran into a similar problem.

main.py:

```
from tkinter import *
import compute
root = Tk()
def save_input():
    global x
    x = int(entry_x.get())
    root.destroy()
Label(root, text = "Enter x").grid(row = 0)
entry_x = Entry(root)
entry_x.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
StartButton = Button(root, text = "Save Input", command = save_input).grid(row = 1)
root.mainloop()
```

compute.py:

```
from main import x
class foo:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an import cycle:  `main` imports `compute` which imports `main`.

There are many possible fixes.  Here are a couple of possible fixes:

1. Move `x` to `compute` and reference it as `compute.x` from `main`.
2. Something more object-oriented: instantiate `foo = compute.foo()` in `main` and interact with `foo.x` from `main`.

Also, you should be protecting the code in `main.py` to prevent execution unless it is invoked as the main module.  See [python.org on **main**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)